# How to properly multi-thread a paint program in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, paint, java.util.concurrent

I'm working on a project I started out of curiosity. The aim of my project is to use Java to create a resource pack in Minecraft. In the end, I wanted to add custom songs to Minecraft. Since I'm fairly new to Java and currently an undergrad, I thought it might be a good idea to explore Java and learn. Anyway, I thought I would try creating my own custom paint program to create a pack image. Here's the issue I'm encountering now:

**I'm modeling the bucket tool feature in some paint programs. I decided to multi-thread it because depending on how big the area I want to paint is, it can be a long task. Specifically, I have issues with overlapping threads. I've never done multi-threading before but I feel like I'm so close to getting it right.**

I've tried using SwingWorker and Thread classes. I ended up finding out that they both reach the exact same issue. So I decided to get rid of SwingWorker and use Thread because it's easier to code. **The paint methods paintImmediately(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight()) and repaint() are very crucial to making this work.** The paintImmediately method is inside the *pixel[p].setColor()* method inside the Pixel class that I wrote, which I don't think is important to know for this question. There's a big difference in implementing and not implementing the repaint() method -- **repaint fixes the graphical issues but causes each thread to execute much slower. Without repaint method, the threads go much faster but they overlap.**

By the way, to make it easier for me to monitor and debug my paint program, I've marked any classes I wrote private inside my main class. I plan on putting the classes into separate java files once the paint program functions the way I wanted it.

**PixelBoard:**

```
private class PixelBoard extends JPanel implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {
    private boolean leftMouse = false;
    private HiddenOptions hiddenOptions;

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent m) {
        leftMouse = (hiddenOptions == null) ? m.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1 : false;
        boolean middleMouse = m.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON2, rightMouse = (hiddenOptions == null) ? m.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3 : false;
        Pixel p = (Pixel) m.getSource();
        if (leftMouse) {
            if (menuBar.isBucket()) {
                ArrayList<Integer> bucket = new Bucket(p.getIndex(), p.getColor()).bucket();
                drawnPixels.addAll(bucket);
            } else {
                setColor(p, colors.getColor());
            }
        } else if (middleMouse) {
            if (hiddenOptions == null)
                hiddenOptions = new HiddenOptions();
        } else if (rightMouse) {
            colors.setColor(p.getColor()); //'colors' is a JColorChooser declared in the Main class
        }
    }
}
```

**Bucket:**

```
private class Bucket implements Runnable {
    private ArrayList<Integer> bucket = new ArrayList<Integer>(), getPixels = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private Color getColor = colors.getColor(), groupColor;

    public Bucket(int startPixel, Color groupColor) {
        this.groupColor = groupColor;
        if (groupColor != getColor) {
            add(startPixel);
            getPixels.add(startPixel);
        }
        new Thread(this).start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (!getPixels.isEmpty()) {
            move();
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<Integer> bucket() {
        return bucket;
    }

    private void add(int p) {
        pixel[p].setColor(getColor);
        pixel[p].setToolTipText(pixel(p));
        container.repaint();
        bucket.add(p);
    }

    private void move() {
        ArrayList<Integer> pix = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int p : getPixels) {
            for (int m : move(p)) {
                if (!bucket.contains(m)) {
                    if (pixel[m].getColor().equals(groupColor)) {
                        add(m);
                        pix.add(m);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        getPixels = pix;
    }

    private boolean[] pixelLocations(int index) {
        boolean topLeftCorner = index == 0, topRightCorner = index == pixels - 1;
        boolean bottomLeftCorner = index == lastPixel - pixels, bottomRightCorner = index == lastPixel - 1;
        boolean leftEdge = index % pixels == 0, rightEdge = (index + 1) % pixels == 0;
        boolean topEdge = index > 0 && index < pixels - 1, bottomEdge = index > lastPixel - pixels && index < lastPixel - 1;
        return new boolean[] {topLeftCorner, topRightCorner, bottomLeftCorner, bottomRightCorner, leftEdge, rightEdge, topEdge, bottomEdge};
    }

    private int[] move(int p) {
        int[] move = {p + 1, p - 1, p + pixels, p - pixels};
        boolean[] location = pixelLocations(p);
        if (location[0])
            move = move(move, new int[] {0, 2});
        else if (location[1])
            move = move(move, new int[] {1, 2});
        else if (location[2])
            move = move(move, new int[] {0, 3});
        else if (location[3])
            move = move(move, new int[] {1, 3});
        else if (location[4])
            move = move(move, new int[] {0, 2, 3});
        else if (location[5])
            move = move(move, new int[] {1, 2, 3});
        else if (location[6])
            move = move(move, new int[] {0, 1, 2});
        else if (location[7])
            move = move(move, new int[] {0, 1, 3});
        return move;
    }

    private int[] move(int[] move, int[] newMove) {
        int[] m = new int[newMove.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++)
            m[i] = move[newMove[i]];
        return m;
    }
}
```

Simply removing the repaint (and paintImmediately) methods causes very obvious impacts:

- Removing the paintImmediately method in Pixel class (not shown here)
  does not show overlap but slows down execution speed of each Thread.
- The paintImmediately method does show results instantly, but you can
  see that some pixels have some overlapping colors from another
  thread.
- Adding the repaint method massively slows down execution
  speed of each thread but also cuts down on graphical overlapping
  visually.
- Removing the repaint method reverts the program back to
  overlapping issues.

**Edit: Using SwingWorker -- I noticed that SwingWorker gives the same exact issue I had when I used the Thread class**

```
private class Bucket extends SwingWorker<ArrayList<Integer>, Void> {
    private ArrayList<Integer> getBucket, getPixels = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private Color groupColor;
    private int startPixel;

    public Bucket(int startPixel, Color groupColor) {
        this.startPixel = startPixel; this.groupColor = groupColor;
        execute();
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Integer> doInBackground() throws Exception {
        ArrayList<Integer> bucket = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Color getColor = colors.getColor(); 
        if (groupColor != getColor) {
            bucket = add(startPixel, getColor, bucket);
            getPixels.add(startPixel);
        }
        while (!getPixels.isEmpty()) {
            move(getColor, bucket);
        }
        return bucket;
    }

    @Override
    protected void done() {
        try {
            getBucket = get();
        } catch (InterruptedException|ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<Integer> getBucket() {
        return getBucket;
    }

    private ArrayList<Integer> add(int p, Color getColor, ArrayList<Integer> bucket) {
        pixel[p].setColor(getColor);
        pixel[p].setToolTipText(pixel(p));
        bucket.add(p);
        return bucket;
    }

    private void move(Color getColor, ArrayList<Integer> bucket) {
        ArrayList<Integer> pix = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int p : getPixels) {
            for (int m : move(p)) {
                if (!bucket.contains(m)) {
                    if (pixel[m].getColor().equals(groupColor)) {
                        bucket = add(m, getColor, bucket);
                        pix.add(m);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        getPixels = pix;
    }

    private int[] move(int p) {
        int[] move = {p+1, p-1, p+pixels, p-pixels};
        boolean[] location = pixelLocations(p);
        if (location[0])
            move = move(move, new int[] {0, 2});
        else if (location[1])
            move = move(move, new int[] {1, 2});
        else if (location[2])
            move = move(move, new int[] {0, 3});
        else if (location[3])
            move = move(move, new int[] {1, 3});
        else if (location[4])
            move = move(move, new int[] {0, 2, 3});
        else if (location[5])
            move = move(move, new int[] {1, 2, 3});
        else if (location[6])
            move = move(move, new int[] {0, 1, 2});
        else if (location[7])
            move = move(move, new int[] {0, 1, 3});
        return move;
    }

    private int[] move(int[] move, int[] newMove) {
        int[] m = new int[newMove.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++)
            m[i] = move[newMove[i]];
        return m;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). One recommendation there is "Pretend you're talking to a busy colleague" which suggests that questions should be concise and focus on the essential information. Another recommendation (which is related to the first one) is to post [mcve].

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that all swing painting should be eventually done on a single thread know as EDT ? For more information see [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html).

Comment: Ah. Thanks for the info. I'll change the code then. I appreciate it.

Comment: @c0der I've switched to using the SwingWorker class. But it's giving me exactly the same issues I had when I used the Thread class.

Comment: Please relate to my first comment.

Comment: You aren't doing the painting on the Swing event thread...

Comment: @c0der ok gotcha.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel How should I properly do the painting on the Swing event thread?